# Need help understanding this ASM code within a C function

Tags: c, assembly

Within a function, we have the following:

```
__asm__("movl $0xe4ffffe4, -4(%ebp)");
```

Does this mean that we move the contents of the memory address 0xe4ffffe4 over to the ebp register?

Comment: It is in AT&T syntax. Maybe sounds more familiar as `mov dword [ebp-4], 0xe4ffffe4` as per Intel syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
movl $0xe4ffffe4, -4(%ebp)
```

Says "move the 4-byte value 0xe4ffffe4 into the slot 4 bytes before the address stored in register ebp."

Answer (score 4):

`-4(%ebp)` means: 4 bytes before the address stored in `ebp`. This address is usually the first local variable. The l prefix of `movl` stands for "long", for integers, this means 4 bytes. So your code means: "move the value 0xE4FFFFE4 in the first local variable which has a size of 4 bytes".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this document.  It's about protecting the call stack by placing a constant value (canary) in ebp, running some code, then verifying that the constant is still there to detect malicious behavior.
http://www.coresecurity.com/files/attachments/StackGuard.pdf